# Getting the API_KEY from SendGrid .env file (Node.js)

Tags: environment-variables, sendgrid, environment, api-key, dotenv

I'm using SendGrid(Node.js) for one of my personal projects. I followed the integration guide to set up my API KEY .env file as following:

```
echo "export SENDGRID_API_KEY='YOUR_API_KEY'" > sendgrid.env
echo "sendgrid.env" >> .gitignore
source ./sendgrid.env
```

My question is... Every time before running the backend locally, I have to first run

```
source ./sendgrid.env
```

In order for the process.env.YOUR_API_KEY be acknowledged where the key is.
But after renamed the **sendgrid.env** file to just **.env**, I don't have to run source anymore.

This is how I call the API KEY

```
require('dotenv').config()

const { validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const Appointment = require('../models/Appointment')
const User = require('../models/User')
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
```

PS. I have set the **dotenv** config at the top of the file but still getting undefined until I changed the file name.

Does anyone know the reason or the logic behind this?? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding it well enough. You have to change it to .env because by default `require('dotenv').config()` point to .env because the parenthesis of config are empty.
To follow the sendgrid way by calling your file sendgrid.env you would have to `require('dotenv').config(sendgrid.env)` and maybe, just `require('dotenv').config(sendgrid)` would be enough. Got to try it to know for sure. But at least from my understanding this is your answer.

Comment: Hey! You are right, that was the problem. I changed my code to ```require('dotenv').config({ path: '.sendgrid.env' })``` and it works. Thanks :)

Here is the documentation for anyone who might be interested in this issue:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv